# wmq-fte precall java failed

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

I am implementing a FTE network using Websphere MQ 7.5.

I have developped a java program to be ran as a precall transfert.
here is my procedure :
  I have updated the agent.properties file with path to java.exe
  restart my agent
  create a new transfert 
  In the call panel, I configure a precall :
     program : java
     argument : -jar c:\PATH\TO\MY\JAR\myJar.jar myArgument

the transfert fails and the error shown is like java does not receive any argument.

When I test my command in a windows prompt it works.

In addition, my first attempt was to run a batch script containing the java command but it did not work either.

I do not want to use an exit as the program is specific to a transfer.

Edit : I have test a simple java -version command and it works.

```
  <preSourceCall>
  <command name="java" retryCount="0" retryWait="0" successRC="0" type="executable">
    <argument>-jar C:\mqfteTest\ExitsJava.jar C:\mqfteTest\userExitTest\FileRef_20121023.txt</argument>
  </command>
</preSourceCall>
```

Error returned :

```
  <callResult outcome="failure" retries="0">
    <result outcome="failure" returnCode="1" time="2012-10-24T12:39:52.419Z">
      <stdout>
        <line/>
        <line>Syntaxe : java [-options] class [args...]</line>
        <line>           (pour l'ex‚cution d'une classe)</line>
        <line>   ou  java [-jar] [-options] jarfile [args...]</line>
         ...
       <line>JVMJ9VM007E Option de ligne de commande non identifiee : -jar C:\mqfteTest\ExitsJava.jar C:\mqfteTest\userExitTest\FileRef_20121023.txt</line>
        <line>Could not create the Java virtual machine.</line>
      </stderr>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to execute my precall:

for the windows platform, I used a batch script and i put the script and the jar in a folder without space in the path.

I did not manage to use the java command and will open a PMR to understand why.

edit :

Finally I have understood why!!
In fact the so called "argumentS" (in the precall conf) are in fact just one argument.

I have also manage to deploy my precall on iseries as400.

the command line is the same but the declaration of shell MUST be

```
 #!/QOpenSys/usr/bin/sh
```

with #!/bin/sh wmq-fte does not manage to catch the exit of the program

Everything works great now.

I also found a strange behaviour (which will aim to another PMR) :

when the files to send are in a subdirectory of the command path, the transfert fail.

Hope this will help some one.

Regards

Comment: What was the result of your PMR with IBM?  I'm trying to execute 'java -jar <jar-name.jar>' as a post-task and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did not open it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I have understood the question. Assuming your aim is to invoke Java class before the transfer begins, you can use MFT exits to achieve that. Here is a [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/sample_source_end_exit.htm) to WMQ MFT v7.5 sample source end user exit.

HTH

Comment: hi thanks for the aswer! I don't want to use an exit because it will be executed in every transfer.